# 6-digits code arrangement

Tags: probability, combinatorics, permutations

6-digit codes with no repeated digits are made by using {1,2,3,4,5,6}. Find the probability that a code chosen at random out of all 6-digit codes made will have both 1 as the first digit and 6 as the last digit but not both.

My answer:

Total probability of arranging the 6-digit codes - probability that has 1 as the first digit and 6 as the last digit.

$\frac{(6! - 4!)}{6!} = \frac{29}{30}$

The answer given is $\frac{4}{15}$.

May I know what I have done incorrectly?

Comment: I do not understand the statement. "[...] will have both 1 as the first digit and 6 as the last digit but not both". The first "both" is rather "either" may be ?

Comment: Did you mean to ask for the probability that the code will have $1$ as a first digit *or* $6$ as the last digit but not both?

Comment: You have subtracted away those codes with 1 first and 6 last, but have still left in all those codes that that have 1 and 6 in the middle somewhere, such as 315624.

Answer (score 5):

The question makes sense only if it is asking for "either A is first XOR B is last"

And when probabilities are asked for, it is often easier to compute them directly rather than by counting permutations.

P(A first & B not last) +P(B last & A not first)
$ = \Large\frac16\frac45 + \frac16\frac45 = \frac4{15}$

Comment: explaining with "XOR" , what a sexy answer it is, my old friend :) $+1$

Comment: @SalmonFish: XX!!$\;\;\;$:)

Comment: Is it obvious why the events 'A first' and 'B not last' are independent?

Comment: @AndreasLenz: The expression $\frac16\frac45$  represents P(A first)*P(B not last | A first) using the general multiplicative principle.

Comment: @trueblueanil okay, I guess I am struggling to see an easy explanation why P(B not last | A first)=$\frac45$. I suppose it is related to the idea that you have 5 choices, because of no repetition, and 4 of them are different from B. My confusion is that, if the previous to last letter is equal to B, one actually has all 5 choices, no?

Comment: @AndreasLenz: $A - - - - -\;\;$ A occupies slot 1. $\;$5 slots are now vacant, but B can't occupy the last, so 4/5.

Comment: Oh my.... I thought "no repeated digits" means that you cannot have the same digit in **consecutive** positions, but you may have them in non-consecutive positions... That'd make the problem a bit different I suppose. Thanks for your time!

Comment: @AndreasLenz: Glad to be of help !$\;\;$:)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the question is either $1$ is first or $6$ is last (either-or translates to the logical exclusive-or), then we can use [inclusion-exclusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle) to compute the probability that $1$ is first or $6$ is last (allowing the possibility that we have both):
$$
\overbrace{\quad\ \frac16\ \quad}^\text{$1$ is first}+\overbrace{\quad\ \frac16\ \quad}^\text{$6$ is last}-\overbrace{\quad\ \frac1{30}\ \quad}^{\substack{\text{$1$ is first}\\\text{and}\\\text{$6$ is last}}}=\overbrace{\quad\ \frac3{10}\ \quad}^{\substack{\text{$1$ is first}\\\text{or}\vphantom{d}\\\text{$6$ is last}}}
$$
To get the probability that we have either one or the other, we need to subtract the probability that we have both (again):
$$
\overbrace{\quad\ \frac3{10}\ \quad}^{\substack{\text{$1$ is first}\\\text{or}\vphantom{d}\\\text{$6$ is last}}}-\overbrace{\quad\ \frac1{30}\ \quad}^{\substack{\text{$1$ is first}\\\text{and}\\\text{$6$ is last}}}=\overbrace{\quad\ \frac4{15}\ \quad}^{\substack{\text{either}\vphantom{g}\\\text{$1$ is first}\\\text{or}\vphantom{d}\\\text{$6$ is last}}}
$$

Answer (score 1):

If you mean "either has a $1$ as the first digit or a $6$ as the final digit, but not both", then there is an issue with your calculation.

You correctly subtracted off the cases where the codes have a $1$ as the first digit AND a $6$ as the last digit, but you did not subtract off the cases where the first digit is NOT a $1$ AND the last digit is NOT a $6$.